# Should I downvote badly formatted posts?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

If I found a horribly formatted post, should I give it a downvote for the terrible formatting along with an edit? Or should I simply edit it?

Comment: Do you think the formatting makes it less clear or less useful? Then downvote. But once the formatting is fixed that reason doesn't apply, so do you remove the downvote, or are there other issues with it?

Comment: 'There are other reasons to downvote something, but "hard to read" is legit. This isn't some grade-school essay contest where you get points just for completing the assignment - if your question *or answer* isn't accessible and understandable by others, it's just noise.' ([Are the Downvoting police too active?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2500/168))

Comment: I save 'em for when they're a disaster.  I mean like comically bad.  <h1>s in the middle of super-indented code that switches back and forth to plaintext randomly, formatting placeholders everywhere `enter code here` BS and just plain bone laziness.

Comment: If you care enough to downvote, you should care enough to fix it with an edit.

Comment: Either way, I would suggest leaving a comment with a link back to this post.

Comment: If you can fix it with an edit then no. Just no....

Comment: I wish I can lock this post

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Remember that you are always free to vote however you wish as long as you don't target people serially or commit other voting fraud.  Now that that's out of the way, here is my take on downvoting poorly formatted posts.

Bad formatting is absolutely a legitimate reason to downvote.  Poor formatting makes posts hard to understand and much less useful.  In extreme cases, it can actually distort/hide real content.  If the formatting is fixed, then you should consider retracting that downvote (unless it is bad for other reasons).

> Or should I simply edit it?

Yes you should "simply" edit the post.  If the formatting isn't too bad that it is easily fixed in an edit, just edit it.  However, if editing the post looks to be an undertaking, then the post itself qualifies to be downvoted because it is unclear/not useful.

Comment: *"Remember that you are always free to vote however you wish as long as you don't target people serially or commit other voting fraud."* Wait a second, no, you are ***always*** free to vote as you wish and there will never be an exception, it's just if you vote serially or fraudulently your votes will likely be reversed.

Comment: @cat: We do take action against users who vote serially or fraudulently - it's not just the system, and it's not just reversing the fraudulent votes. So, no, you aren't free to target users or cheat the system.

Comment: @cat: Depends on your definition of "free to". I don't think anyone sane would argue that you're "free to murder people" just because you can physically carry out the act despite being thrown in jail afterwards. And I'll let you know, if I ever find anyone sane...

Comment: RIP @Lightness Races in Orbit

Comment: @BoltClock: It's been emotional.

Answer (score 19):

> Usually, people don't learn a thing until they are forced to learn it.

A **horribly formatted post** always deserves a down-vote. I suggest leaving a comment for the DV and mention that formatting was the reason you DVed it. If the OP didn't spend too much time in *trying to format it properly*, and only wants his question answered (or answer upvoted), then he deserves a DV. Now, I am not talking about small formatting errors. I am specifically talking about OP dumping several lines of code (that isn't formatted in the question) and expecting an answer.

If you choose to DV it but don't edit it, then I would recommend going back and checking if it was edited and then removing the DV if it was edited (to make it proper) because many new users don't understand how to post a good question / answer.

Comment: Surely we should be downvoting the *post*, not the person. After editing the post, presumably it doesn't deserve a downvote... so doing so would be *personal*... something I'd try to avoid.

Comment: We've been lead to believe that voting is and should remain anonymous. Commenting on votes you cast removes that anonymity and rarely ends in anything other than arguing about the vote itself. Its one thing to comment on the merits of a post or to educate a user about community etiquette and guidelines, it is another thing entirely to comment on an anonymous vote. The former is usually a constructive exercise, while the latter is usually not. Not to mention the fact that comments starting with +1 or -1 are blocked by the system to deter people from posting such comments.

Comment: So you're saying [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/354038/1) would still deserve a downvote because of its original formatting? Since editing its gone on to be one of the top questions in the python tag

Comment: @JonSkeet - Then what would be the motivation for the OP to "improve his post"?. If the post is salvageable and if someone ahs enough time to improve it, he could decide to improve it and at the same time let the OP know that his post was bad. Why would anyone bother improving their posts when there is no pressure for them to do it?.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I understand why voting has to be anonymous (to prevent revenge down-voting and stuff like that) but honestly, if we don't tell a person where he is wrong because we are afraid that it will affect the person who is telling **what is right**, how would he even learn to correct his mistakes?. We usually DV / CV posts that show lack of effort (or are poor) . How is DV / CVing  a post for putting less effort while creating it any different?

Comment: @Sayse - It is a good question. It doesn't have sever formatting issues. I am talking about posts that are horribly formatted.

Comment: In a language where whitespace is vital, it could be argued that it has severe formatting issues since it may hinder any potential errors in the code - but my point is that editing made it a highly respected question. You could argue that some of your [first questions](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18887197/1) have formatting issues, not everyone is aware of markdown or how to style posts when first starting out which is why we (should) vote on the content

Comment: @Sayse - " not everyone is aware of markdown or how to style posts when first starting out which is why we (should) vote on the content " ==> Then why would a person who is only interested in getting answers care about about improving his / her posts?. Yes, some of my first questions have formatting issues and honestly some DVs did help me improve my questions / answers (that includes formatting as well).

Comment: @TheLostMind: I'd expect the comment to be an indication that the OP should do the work themselves next time... and next time, maybe no-one *will* be willing to reformat it themselves. It does sound like you're trying to use downvotes on the *person*, not the *post*.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes. We need to make it clear that the OP needs to reformat the code himself / herself. I am not suggesting going through his posts and DVing them (which would imply voting on the person), I am merely suggesting taking a tough stand to ensure that people don't have to edit poorly formatted code in posts.

Comment: @TheLostMind: I normally edit and add a comment saying that they should do it themselves next time. If you want to downvote, that's reasonable *if* you've still left the post broken (because then it's still a bad post). But downvoting a good post is contrary to the point of the score - a measure of how good the post is *right now*.

Comment: @JonSkeet -Agreed. Just to clarify, a post that doesn't need too much editing effort is OK. A dump of code where the OP means to say - *"format it for me so that others can answer it"* deserves a DV in my opinion. If I see the OP trying to improve his post by editing and responding to people's feedback, I usually remove my DV.

Comment: The *post* deserves a downvote, because it's poor. If you edit it, it no longer deserves the DV.  It's up to individual users how much effort they want to put into editing posts for OPs, of course.

Comment: @TheLostMind what would you have thought of my [first post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588331/simple-cross-tabulation-in-pandas)?

Comment: @JonClements - I would say that you decided to *improve your future posts on your own* :P.  And that post wasn't *unsalvageable*. I would have said that it was bad if you had 25 lines of code where the person editing it would have to spend 5 mins trying to match starting brace with edning brace

Comment: @TheLostMind - Its not "why would a person", its why *does* a person. And thats simple, over time people realise that the clearer a question is, the more accurate/relevant the answers they receive become. Granted I can think of a few that this doesn't apply towards, but the vast majority of people I see asking further questions tend to have better formatting and better quality questions

Comment: @Sayse - My suggestion is to accelerate that process by forcing them take a look at the posts immediately. Also note that this might not change the people whose hopeless posts are almost always edited to acceptable standards by SO members (no complaints here)

Comment: 1. I didn't say we shouldn't tell people where they are wrong. By all means comment on everything that you think could be improved. I'm only saying don't comment on your votes, because that is rarely constructive. 2. You can downvote for whatever reason, or lack thereof, that you like. Downvoting makes the world go 'round.

Comment: There is so much that is wrong with this answer. Voting on users, commenting on downvotes, constantly revisiting downvoted posts, not editing out of spite. How is it that any of this guidance is supported by a moderator?

Comment: "*he* deserves a DV"? Vote on the state of the post. If it is in good shape there is no reason to leave a downvote there. You shouldn't be using votes as punitive measures on users themselves. If it was in bad shape and nothing was done, it is also not reasonable to ask people to constantly check in to see if the post was improved. You state "I would recommend going back and checking". but that is simply not reasonable. It would waste too much time to constantly observe the state of posts users have downvoted.

Comment: If you feel that a post is so horrible that it would take a herculean effort from yourself or even anyone else to even make it *readable*, then by all means just leave a downvote and move on. Maybe leave a comment too if you think the person can read, but you don't even *need* to tell them it was the reason you downvoted - it'll become *completely* obvious to them once the downvotes begin piling up over time. But if you're going to edit a post anyway, *thereby removing the problem altogether*, it makes no sense whatsoever to still downvote on the basis of a problem that *you removed*.

Comment: I can tell you that the problem of users not having to learn to format their posts properly themselves because the community is so eager to help clean up after them bothers *me* even more than it does you, but this is not the way to solve it.

Comment: @TravisJ - You are free to write your own answer (like I did) and any person (mod or otherwise) has the right to say what he thinks is right. My opinion is that people should not spend too much time cleaning really bad posts when the person posting them isn't trying to do the same. I am not asking people to vote on users, when I said "he deserves a DV" , I meant "his post deserves a DV" (my bad). I don't even know from where you got the "not editing out of spite" thing?. I find it to be amusing coz people who care for SO's quality should step up to fix a problem which the OP should fix.

Comment: Since when downvotes deserve comments/explanations/excuses? Not all of them do.

Comment: I think I'll distill this a bit:  unless the juice (a good post) is worth the squeeze (going through and editing it), it's probably better to downvote it and move on.  I don't see any malice or anything here encouraging action against the person directly, but I do see it as a more direct variation on my personal train of thought when I see really poorly formatted questions.

Comment: I prefer the word "inspired" instead of "forced".

Answer (score 6):

I'm personally more inclined to fix posts with formatting problems rather than simply down vote them. Of course, if there are *serious* problems, then I may simply close vote. If the question is old and almost eligible for deletion, then I may down vote instead.

To think of it another way, there are two basic choices you can make:

- Spend 30 seconds deciding if you will down vote (and then decide if you will comment about said down vote).
- Spend 30 seconds and edit. It may be more or less time, depending on the post, its issues and if you have full edit privileges or not.

Most people have some sense of pride and would format things properly if they knew how; I think that editing helps that process. The thing to ask is really: will down voting improve the user's behavior? I doubt the answer would be "yes" in most cases.

Comment: I remember learning about better ways to format from people helpfully editing my posts.  For repeat offenders that keep posting garbage, it can make sense to just downvote instead of fixing it for them.  But for very new users, this may be the best way to educate them.

Comment: @PeterCordes - The problem is when we say *repeat offenders*, we will be targeting *users* and I don't want to go in that direction. Sometimes this approach involves going through the OP's questions and also having the time to separate out OP's original posts / edits from the edits of SO members. Quite a herculean task IMHO

Comment: @TheLostMind: Great point.  I personally only apply that if I see obvious pure laziness (rather than ignorance) from a user with over 500 rep or something (they should know better), or if I remember editing a user's previous question recently and they still haven't learned.  (I follow `[x86]`, `[assembly]`, and other relatively low volume tags where it's possible to remember a good fraction of repeat posters, and be able to say "oh, that guy".)

Comment: @TheLostMind: I just went and found a recent comment thread where I got on the OP's case for being lazy.  I'd forgotten that [the issue was a picture of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286022/assembler-turn-3-lines-into-1#comment63991112_38286022), which I wasn't going to OCR or transcribe for them, which is why I didn't also fix it.    (The OP's comment replies are now deleted, but included accusing me of being lazy for not wanting to type out the text from an image!).

Comment: @PeterCordes - Yes. I agree with your comment on that post. Question readers are supposed to be lazy. Its the responsibility of the OP to correct the formatting (or in your case add actual code instead of  images)

Answer (score 4):

Down-vote and move on. Do not waste any more of your time on a truly *horribly* formatted post. If the asker could not be bothered to format it well, why should anyone bother trying to read or answer it.

If it is poorly formatted, but otherwise good, consider editing the post.

Comment: Do you go back and check later if that down vote is still deserved?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is vote to close as not clear what you are asking.
Severe formatting problems make a question not clear.
If information is missing and bad formatting I will ask for information and please format.
If they don't perform either in a couple hours and have been on I will vote to close.

Down voting does not seem to be very effective.
If you down vote and comment you may get retaliatory down votes.

Comment: Is the lack of punctuation in your post a social experiment? `:-)`

Comment: @halfer It is not a social experiment

Comment: Ah... [I am not sure you should be answering this Meta question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031209/regex-for-first-page). `:-p` (In case it's not clear, punctuation is much appreciated here, and automatically wrapping paragraphs are preferred to manual line-breaks. Some community members are bit more lenient with new users, but 28K users are certainly held to a higher standard).

Comment: @halfer Sorry if you find that to be a poorly formatted question.  You could have commented.

Comment: @halfer And I would consider this to be less than optimal formatting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359051/sql-reduce-dates-to-range-start-end/38402397#38402397  I don't want to get into it with you.  Got it - you don't like manual line breaks.

Comment: @halfer I don't want to get into with you and not deliberately misinterpreting.  I know how wrapping works.  You made your point 3 comments ago.  I got it.  I feel like you are getting hostile with me and I chose to not continue this conversation.  But that post *is* an example and you would never find SQL or code from me with inconsistent formatting.

Comment: I am aware to you it is either wrong or right and you have a definition of wrong and right.  I used some much softer words "And I would consider this to be less than optimal formatting."   I don't want to get into it with you.  Thank for you for your candid feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117454/discussion-between-halfer-and-paparazzi).

Answer (score -2):

If you really care about the reasoning behind the vote you're about to cast (which is completely irrelevant in every way, shape, and form), here's an ASCII flowchart to help you muddle through the complexities of voting.

```
Can the post be improved in any way whatsoever?
    |
    |__ Yes: Edit _______
    |                    |
    |__ No: Don't edit __|
                         |
                         |__ Is the post useful and clear?
                                |
                                |__ Yes: Do you think the post is worthy of an upvote?
                                |       |
                                |       |__ Yes: Upvote
                                |       |
                                |       |__ No: Don't vote
                                |
                                |__ No: Do you think the post is worthy of a downvote?
                                        |
                                        |__ Yes: Downvote
                                        |
                                        |__ No: Don't vote
```

That said, you can vote for whatever reason, or lack thereof, that you feel like... so long as you aren't being all fraudulent and naughty about it.

Comment: This flow implies that you should vote based on the new state of the post after editing. However there are some cases where the original was so lazy/demanding that it deserves a DV, even if it was salvageable.

Comment: @halfer Well, that would be voting on something other than the content itself in it's current condition, in which case that fits into the "vote for whatever reason, or lack thereof, that you feel like" part of this answer. The downvote tooltip doesn't say "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear, not useful, overly demanding, or lazy", so technically you're wrong, but again, you can vote for whatever reason, or lack thereof that you feel like.

Comment: I'm right _and_ wrong? Lordy, I think I might explode! `/me defies physics ;-)`

Comment: @halfer Technically you're wrong, as far as the tooltip goes, but realistically you're right, because there is no requirement for reason when voting, just a requirement of not being fraudulent or naughty about it.

Answer (score -12):

Bad formatting is not a reason to downvote. We should vote on the *content*, not on the *form*.

The formatting may not even be the OP's choice; our site is community-edited, and there are some seriously bad editors out there... whose edits all too often get robo-approved by careless reviewers.

Also, there is some choice in formatting. For example, some people want stack traces to be in `code markdown`, others believe they should be in quote markdown. A point can be made for both style choices.

If you can spare the time to edit, then edit.   If you can't spare the time to edit, but have some time to comment - then comment. If you can do neither - then vote on the content, or leave it be. There's plenty of posts with bad *content* to spend your votes on.

Comment: *Bad formatting is not a reason to downvote. We should vote on the content, not on the form.* ==> Then what is forcing the OP into improving his / her posts?. His 100th question (say 2 years later) will perhaps be as bad as his first because anonymous people on SO spend their valuable time in improving the OPs lazy posts.

Comment: I view formatting as part of the overall quality of the post. I have no problem in downvoting a post based on its formatting - but I would undo that downvote if the formatting were improved regardless of who improved it. (Note that most poor formatting I've seen hasn't been a matter of choice - it's been a matter of pure laziness.)

Comment: @TheLostMind If the posts are otherwise good, there are more than enough users who will happily edit them into shape. IMO that's one of the main reasons why we have community editing. In the cases where sloppy formatting is a result of laziness, the laziness usually shows up in the content as well.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - We are wasting time of SO members because someone doesn't know how post a proper question or is too lazy to format code correctly in his posts. This is a problem. I don't understand (as Jon points out) why formatting isn't considered part of the post's quality?. My point is *why should the community be responsible for handling (and spend time) such formatting issues?* . It is the OP's responsibility. A couple of mistakes are always OK. A whole post without formatting is bad IMHO.

Comment: Consider this - if the formatting is so bad that I can't even figure out what the hell the user is saying, how should I vote? Or should I abstain?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Well, laziness can be a choice in itself depending on whom you ask...

Comment: @BoltClock Then the post has a content problem, not a formatting problem.

Comment: @S.L.Barth So you're asserting that it's not possible for the formatting of a post to be bad enough to prevent people from easily understanding it?  I would reject the assertion that there's no way for a post to be formatted badly enough as to be not reasonably understandable, even if the underlying content is entirely understandable when formatted well.

Comment: @Servy Are the multiple negatives in your second sentence deliberate, an attempt to illustrate the point? But, my point is that if you can't make heads nor tails from a post... then it's not merely a formatting issue. I thought this question was about formatting, but I'm getting the impression people now interpret it much broader.

Comment: I think it is mostly to do with the black & whiteness of the statement; "Bad formatting is not a reason to downvote". Usually it is no reason, I agree as *usually* it can be edited into shape. But I make one exception: if you turn the post into something that you'd find in the average facebook page, you get a downvote no questions asked. I'm talking about aggressive use of emotes, bad abbreviations and abuse of capitalisation. The reason being: a comment is not going to help when someone is hooked into that style of communication.

Comment: @Gimby Could be. Normally a post like that has many more problems than that. But let's consider the hypothetical case: an answer that solves a problem properly, helps many... but suffers from emoticons, boldfacing, txt spk and so on. Should we signal that this hypothetical answer is bad, simply because the presentation sucks? All it takes is an edit, and we're not lacking people who are willing to edit.

Comment: Downvoters, I'd appreciate if you considered the following scenario: suppose you're away from SO for a few weeks - for whatever reason. You come back to find that a number of your posts have been "improved" by an editor spamming them full of **boldface**, `backticks` and _italics_, and are heavily downvoted as a consequence. Are these downvotes OK, even though _you never chose or approved of the bad formatting?_

Comment: @S.L.Barth you make a point to consider, but effectively with those poor edits in place the content has become really poor and so might be downvote worthy, with the consequences that the original author gets points deducted for it which is unfortunate. Luckily the more experienced users are trained to spot that the content is edited and will rollback to minimize the damage.